# Apache ignite download website is broken

Tags: ignite

I tried to go to the download location and download the binaries (or even the src) https://ignite.apache.org/download.html#binaries

I can see the link pointing to the following: 
https://ignite.apache.org/[preferred]/[distdir]/1.6.0/apache-ignite-fabric-1.6.0-bin.zip
but I get 404 response

Answer (score 1):

poking around the directory structure, I managed to find the real link : 
https://www.apache.org/dist/ignite/1.6.0/apache-ignite-1.6.0-src.zip

still I suspect the official download links should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In case this happens, choose a mirror using the 'Selected mirror' dropdown. The page should choose the closest mirror automatically and it works in most cases, but it's a bit buggy and sometimes you have to do this manually.